# How to execute commands for Android application

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to enable debug mode for Firebase Analytics as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#android). I tried running this code in my Xamarin.Android application:

```
string commandToRun = "adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.my.app";
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(commandToRun);
```

And it crashes with this error:

> Java.IO.IOException has been thrown Cannot run program "adb": error=2,
> No such file or directory

I am running on a simulator.

Comment: adb is a tool you run on the desktop, not the device

Comment: How can I use it on Mac?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/adb

Comment: Is it possible to use adb with a simulator?

Comment: Yes.  The docs I linked to explicitly discuss using with the emulator

Comment: I run the command `./adb -s emulator-5554 shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.my.app` and I do not get any response/output. Is that normal?

Comment: Just to answer my own question, yes it is normal as it worked.

Comment: Hi @Drake, could you please post the solution you used as an answer so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)